# Merge an action button commands to main page

Tags: php

I have a page that called admin.php that has some cods and buttons. my problem is one of the buttons apply an action code that is originally HTML code but i converted it to php and the code is like this:

```
echo "<form action=\"write.php\" method=\"post\">\n"; 
echo " <p>your MoD name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"mdname\" /></p>\n"; 
echo " <p><input type=\"submit\" /></p>\n"; 
echo "</form>\n";
```

this code calls the write.php and write.php code is this:

```
<?php
header ('Location: admin.php ');
$myFile = "methods\actmod.txt";
unlink($myFile);
$handle = fopen("methods\actmod.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

this code writes some data to txt file that called actmod.txt and returns to the admin page. i wanted to ask is there any way that i can merge write.php to the main admin.php page so when i hit the submit  button in the admin page it won use any external file and runs the commands directly from admin page and i wont have any external files behind the admin page?

i have seen lots of pages that has address like this "http://site.com/admin.php?act=write

i hope every body understand what i mean. i am new to php and i searched a lot and i appreciate to anybody's help. 
thank you

Comment: What does "marge" mean? Is it "merge"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your admin.php

```
<?php
$post = count($__POST) > 0 ? true : false;
if ($post) {
    // do the work you are doing in write.php
} else {
   // do the work you are already doing in admin.php
}
```

There may be better ways to identify the request being POST or GET, I am just trying to give you a hint and rest is yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

use this in your admin.php

```
<?php

if(array_key_exists('action', $_GET)&&$_GET['action']=='write') {
    $myFile = "methods\actmod.txt";
    // unlink($myFile); deletes your file, if you want to ADD text, don't :)
    $handle = fopen($myFile, "a");
    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
        fwrite($handle, $variable);
        fwrite($handle, "=");
        fwrite($handle, $value);
        fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    }
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
    fclose($handle);
}

echo "<form action=\"admin.php?action=write\" method=\"post\">\n"; 
echo " <p>your MoD name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"mdname\" /></p>\n"; 
echo " <p><input type=\"submit\" /></p>\n"; 
echo "</form>\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: @MrBG How my answer was different from this answer?

Comment: @vikas it's more detailed. You missed the answer in how to only act if a get parameter called `action` is present AND you missed the answer about how to ADD lines to the text file!